# cosmos db nested query with geometry locations

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I can´t figure it out how to select.

json example

```
    "inserted": "2022-11-22T17:40:40.0303547Z",
    "packagekey": "b53b8bfb-68b7-4ad1-aacb-b5868d4b4657",
    "ismoved": true,
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            16.788592,
            54.454656
        ]
    },
    "id": "d8d4c25e-9800-4dc8-8185-fe18802ab1ff",
    "partionkey": "b53b8bfb-68b7-4ad1-aacb-b5868d4b4657",
    "key": "8d8cc237-3940-41e3-badf-116cea092756",
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {}
}
```

same package new location new time

```
    "inserted": "2022-11-23T17:40:40.0303547Z",
    "packagekey": "b53b8bfb-68b7-4ad1-aacb-b5868d4b4657",
    "ismoved": true,
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            17.788592,
            55.454656
        ]
    },
    "id": "5bb05a5e-d06c-4c69-a76e-5c84cbfdea24",
    "partionkey": "b53b8bfb-68b7-4ad1-aacb-b5868d4b4657",
    "key": "3e1d4166-893d-41eb-86e9-c4521e5119f9",
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {}
}
```

another package on the same locaion that the other had passed

```
    "inserted": "2022-09-23T17:40:40.0303547Z",
    "packagekey": "945fcf8a-e03d-4686-aecb-e54dceb7bd6e",
    "ismoved": true,
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
             16.788592,
            54.454656
        ]
    },
    "id": "659b284c-febe-4428-bda7-9a356e9a7b3b",
    "partionkey": 945fcf8a-e03d-4686-aecb-e54dceb7bd6e",
    "key": "78be825f-de86-4244-99f8-5bc1b2e938b8",
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {}
}
```

I have many object like these and the packagekey indicates a package and the geometry is a location. Each package have 1 or more locations depedning how it is moved.

How can I select all packages(each package have a packagekey) on a certain location I use the where like

```
where ST_DISTANCE(c.geometry, {'type':'Point', 'coordinates':[16.788592, 54.454656]}) <= 1
```

And there can be many packages on the same location(stacked)

But in the example above I just want to see packagekey 945fcf8a-e03d-4686-aecb-e54dceb7bd6e

I have tried like

```
SELECT c.packagekey, c.geometry, c.inserted
FROM c
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(c1.inserted) AS maxInserted, c1.packagekey
    FROM c c1
    GROUP BY c1.packagekey
) maxDates
ON c.inserted = maxDates.maxInserted AND c.packagekey = maxDates.packagekey
```

But its not correct

Comment: Have you tried adding `ORDER BY` with the `inserted` property? Other than that... not sure what specific issue you're running into. Can you have multiple packages with the same `packagekey` and only want the latest one? Or maybe something else? Please edit to provide specifics.

Comment: I have a document for every new position for a package. And there are multiple packages . This cause the trouble, If I select I gets all packages that had passed the position. I want just want the packages that have just that as lastposition

Comment: Can you edit the source data package with more locations and date and share the expected result for that input?

Comment: The source entity/document above is orginal. And when a package is moved it gets a new document with new insered date and a new location. Maby it should be redesigned to have a array of geometrys  and inserts in the same document, if that is easier to solve,

Comment: Please edit to add clarity to your question. Not quite sure what you mean, based on your comments (like... show maybe more than one sample doc, and show what you're trying to achieve as output). Also: regarding an array of geometry items: just remember that 1) this creates an unbounded-array situation where you could exceed the maximum size of a single document, and 2) you'd now have to perform array-searching (via `ARRAY_CONTAINS`), or have to do self-joins to get what you're looking for - this might not help you.

Comment: I have tried to explain more details. 3 examples and the result and an example of my try(thats not working)

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have rewrote the question with more details and more example. And expected result.

Answer (score -1):

not much experienced but pleas let me know the result ?

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM c
WHERE c.inserted = (SELECT MAX(c2.inserted) FROM c c2)
ORDER BY c.inserted DESC
```

here c represents the alias for the documents in the collection. We use the TOP 1 clause to retrieve only the latest package and then where the inserted property is equal to the maximum inserted value in the collection. The result is ordered by inserted in descending order.

Comment: Thanks but then I just recive one. I want to recive multiple packages on one location, thats the problem not just on.